# odds of strstr performance

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, visual-c++

I am performing a few benchmarks of my code, and I decided to use `strstr` performance as a reference point. On my PC performance of scanning all text of ~7mb file (preloaded into RAM) is about 10Gb/sec.
The strange thing is that when I copied code of strstr function from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src\strstr.c" to my program, it performed **much** worse - about 650 Mb/sec. Code was like this:

```
char * __cdecl strstr2 (
    char * str1,
    const char * str2
    )
{
    char *cp = (char *) str1;
    char *s1, *s2;

    if ( !*str2 )
        return((char *)str1);

    while (*cp)
    {
        s1 = cp;
        s2 = (char *) str2;

        while ( *s1 && *s2 && !(*s1-*s2) )
            s1++, s2++;

        if (!*s2)
            return(cp);

        cp++;
    }

    return(NULL);

}
```

Compiling all code in Release, all compiler options default, running without debugger.
Is this difference due to some compiler options, or code in `strstr.c` is not the real code used in compiled CRT, or something else?

UPD I'm using `QueryPerformanceCounter` to measure timing. Every test is repeated 500 times, after this I calculate average speed and start the next test. (currently I'm comparing 2 tests - CRT's strstr and copied strstr2)

Comment: How many times did you scan the file?

Comment: Benchmarking is hard, although it shouldn't be *that* hard ... Still, you should include some more detail about how you tested this. Quite strange code, too. You can compare it to the GNU libc code [here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strstr.c;h=b2f8e74caeba5a4e7d2a4bad3daf5e0a6189d2c6;hb=HEAD) but it's a bit more ... involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Microsoft CRT probably uses the assembler version of `strstr` found in `VC\crt\src\intel\strstr.asm`. On my system (Visual Studio 10.0) the inner loop looks like this:

```
loop_start:
        mov     al,[esi]            ; put next char from str1 into al
        add     esi,1               ; increment pointer in str1
in_loop:
        cmp     al,dl
        je      first_char_found

        test    al,al               ; end of str1?
        jnz     loop_start          ; no, go get another char from str1
```